# Refactor a large generated method into smaller methods?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

Using EF 6 and "Code First from database" it generates a "OnModelCreating" that is 20k lines approximately 688k of code against our large (650+ tables) database. This causes IIS to append as it is larger than the 32-bit 256kb stack limit. I do not think there is any way to have EF put the Fluent API model bindings per class, which would clearly solve this problem.

To solve this problem currently I have to make smaller "OnModelCreatingX" methods and call those from the "OnModelCreating" method - ya rly.

Is there any refactor tool to take a huge method and split that method into smaller methods?

Comment: Why does it matter how big is the source code file since it gets compiled into dlls?

Comment: Because it throws a overflow exception on the W3C.exe process. Same problem as this guy has https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=25837

Comment: But if you are using "Code First" you are in control how big your methods will be. It's kinda confusing as it stands as to why you are experiencing this.

Comment: The "OnModelCreating" method is generated by using the "Code First from Database" generation when used against an existing database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. I guess it might just have to be a one off to split those methods into smaller classes since you will only ever generate the initial files once.

Comment: When changes are done to our schema (which is unfortunately frequently) we use "Code First from database" to update existing POCO classes, create new POCO classes and update the DBContext. When this happens the "OnModelCreating" gets regenerated as well and requires manually splitting up into 4 different "OnModelCreatingX" methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have to edit the generated code, could you try to split it out it into different files and convert it to a partial class?

Comment: A single (too large) "OnModelCreating" is generated by the "Code First from Database" in the generated DBContext class. Creating a partial class won't solve this as the single "OnModelCreating" method is generated by the EF tool.